# Row convert to column in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My table value is

```
    Esino  ym       workeddays  name
      1   200906        25        a 
      1   200907        24        a
      1   200908        27        a 
      2   200906         22       b
      2   200907        25....    b
```

I nedd out output is

```
     Esino   ym1     ym2    ym3      w1    w2   w3   name
      1      200906  200907 200908  25     24   27   a
      2      200906  200907  200908  22    25    21   b..
```

Condition is

1. The ym is my input i given between month for dynamic for eg 200906 to 200912 or 200901 to 200906
2. workeddays this also depend upon employee presents

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivoting - have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663505/denormalizing-data-maybe-a-pivot), very close to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this sort of thing using [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Dynamic Pivoting. Have a look [Problem in dynamic pivoting + sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620480/problem-in-dynamic-pivoting-sql-server-2005)